# Adaptive authentication using email or sms OTP - Solved

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have wso2 version 5.8.0 and want to make adaptive authentication using email or sms. What needs to be prepared to make adaptive authentication using email or sms to confirm from the client / user.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this documentation for configuring SMS otp authenticator https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Configuring+SMS+OTP and refer this for configuring email otp authenticator https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Configuring+Email+OTP.

You can configure smsotp and email otp authenticator as second step authenticators. Bydefault these connectors are shipped with IS5.8.0

1. **Step1: basic**
2. **Step2: multi option- sms/email otp**

Authentication with sms and email otp can be done without adaptive script. If you want to do some manipulation, you can use an adaptive authentication script. Please follow these documents for further reference.

https://medium.com/@gayanmadusanka_80721/introduction-to-adoptive-authentication-with-wso2-identity-server-5-7-0-release-c3dec5aff895

https://madurangasblogs.blogspot.com/2018/12/adaptive-authentication-with-wso2.html